# how to remove x1 and x2 labels in plotEqn

Tags: r, label

Hello I'm fairly new to R programming language an I'm trying to plot an equation using PlotEqn() function but I can't seem to remove the x1 and x2 labels located in x and y axis respectively. How do I remove this?

```
A = matrix(c(1,19,1,25),2,2)
b = c(95,2027)
plotEqn(A,b,labels=FALSE)
```

this is my code
i just want to remove the labels as circled so i can insert my own which are named. How do i do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2szF.png)

Comment: What package does `plotEqn` come from?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the axis labels with vars=c("x-axis","y-axis").

```
A = matrix(c(1,19,1,25),2,2)
b = c(95,2027)
plotEqn(A,b,labels=FALSE,vars=c("",""))
```

Comment: thank you so much. it worked. i've been at this for hours and turns out i misunderstood vars.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. Please make sure to accept the answer then. Thx.